# Why cant i run my meteor clone project

Tags: meteor, runtime-error

I have cloned my meteor project in an other files but when I try to run it I get the  error below and i dont know why and why i cant run it. Can you help me ?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should remove `.meteor/local` folder in the cloned project.